# How to connect android app with Cassandra database on local machine?

Tags: android, cassandra

I want to store data to a Cassandra database, but i don't know how. Can anyone give me some direction to go ? thanks so much.

Comment: What is your DBMS? means MYSQL or what?

Comment: I think you should build Rest API to to communicate with Cassandra. Look at this example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. This is pure Java solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the examples to get you started:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver/java-driver/quick_start/qsQuickstart_c.html

Just my opinion - but not sure I would connect directly from an Android application to my DB directly. I would probably build some service layer in between and expose it over HTTP, HTTP/2 etc..